# Sum total of a Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Collection file in Laravel, as you can see I have a "totalventa" field, I would like to sum that field of each record in the Collection, but I don't know how it could be, thank you.

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Resources;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    
    class VentaCollection extends ResourceCollection
    {
        /**
         * Transform the resource collection into an array.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return $this->collection->transform(function($row, $key) {
    
                return [
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'fecha' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->fecha)),
                    'items' => $row->detalles,
                    'totalventa' => $row->total(),
                    'subtotalventa' => $row->subtotal(),
                    'igvventa' => $row->igv(),
                    'notas' => $row->notas,
                    'observaciones' => $row->observaciones,
                    'pdf' => $row->enlace_pdf,
                    'estado' => $row->estado,
                    
                    
    
                ];
            })
        }
    }
```

I want to join as one more field of the collection, something like "total sum" ...

```
$records = Venta::where('tienda_id',$id)
                ->whereIn('estado', $filtro)
                ->whereYear('fecha', Carbon::now()->year)
                ->whereMonth('fecha', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(env('ITEMS_PER_PAGE', 10));
                return new VentaCollection($records);
```

Comment: side note, don't use `env` outside of config files

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$records_Sum = Venta::where('tienda_id',$id)
                ->whereIn('estado', $filtro)
                ->whereYear('fecha', Carbon::now()->year)
                ->whereMonth('fecha', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->get()->sum('totalventa');
```

Comment: it would seem this isn't a database field, `totalventa`, it is a computed field they are adding to the transformed data